# What I learned about inserting data into a table using external tables, views, procedures, and how to write those procedures

Tags: oracle

Before: useless question about a missing comma that got down voted.

After: a potentially less useless summary of what I learned:

- tables and views should not be created in a procedure.
- If you are not supplying any run-time values, there is no reason to construct a dynamic sql statement.

What my code looks like now:

```
CREATE TABLE purified_enz_stage1
    (
      construct_id NUMBER(10),
      n_term VARCHAR2 (50),
      enz_name VARCHAR2 (50),
      c_term VARCHAR2 (50),
      cpp VARCHAR2 (50),
      mutations VARCHAR2 (50),
      g_batch VARCHAR2 (50),
      expr_system VARCHAR2 (50),
      emptycol VARCHAR2(50),
      purified_enz_id VARCHAR2 (50),
      g_id VARCHAR2 (50),
      p_batch VARCHAR2 (50),
      final_buffer_system VARCHAR2 (50),
      buffer_mol NUMBER (6, 2),
      final_nacl NUMBER (4),
      final_ph NUMBER (4, 2),
      final_add VARCHAR2 (50),
      yield NUMBER (6, 2),
      concentration NUMBER (6, 2))
    ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
    TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY data_to_input
    ACCESS PARAMETERS (
        RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE 
        SKIP 1
        BADFILE bad_files:'badflie_insert_into_pur_connector_from_purified_enz.bad'
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL 
        ) 
    LOCATION ('PURIFIED_ENZ.CSV')
    ) REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW purified_enz_stage2 AS SELECT

      ext.construct_id,
      n_term,
      enz_name,
      c_term,
      cpp,
      mutations,
      ext.g_batch,
      ext.expr_system,
      emptycol,
      purified_enz_id,
      g_id,
      p_batch,
      final_buffer_system,
      buffer_mol,
      final_nacl,
      final_ph,
      final_add,
      yield,
      concentration,
      pr.produced_id 

FROM purified_enz_stage1 ext INNER JOIN produced pr
ON pr.construct_id = ext.construct_id
AND pr.g_batch = ext.g_batch
AND pr.expr_system = ext.expr_system;


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_into_purified 
AS

records_in_source NUMBER;
record_in_err_table NUMBER;
records_in_target_before NUMBER;
records_in_target_after NUMBER;

BEGIN
    
    DELETE FROM ERR$_PURIFIED_ENZ;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO records_in_source FROM purified_enz_stage1;
    SELECT COUNT (*) INTO records_in_target_before FROM purified_enz;
    
    
    INSERT 
    INTO purified_enz 
        (
        g_id,
        p_batch,
        final_buffer_system,
        buffer_mol,
        final_nacl,
        final_ph,
        final_add,
        yield,
        concentration ) 
    SELECT  
        produced_id,
        p_batch,    
        final_buffer_system,
        buffer_mol,
        final_nacl,
        final_ph,
        final_add,
        yield,
        concentration 
    FROM purified_enz_stage2 
    LOG ERRORS REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
    
    COMMIT;
    SELECT COUNT (*) INTO records_in_target_after FROM purified_enz;
    SELECT COUNT (*) INTO record_in_err_table FROM ERR$_PURIFIED_ENZ;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Records in source file: ' || (records_in_source));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Records updated: ' || (records_in_target_after - records_in_target_before));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Records rejected: ' || (record_in_err_table));
END insert_into_purified;
/
```

Comment: Aside from your question, why are you using dynamic sql here?  You are not supplying any run-time values, so there is no reason to construct a dynamic sql statement.  And as a debugging device when you _do_ use dynamic sql, you should assign the constructed SQL to a variable (let's call it v_sql), then display that with "dbms_output.put_line(v_sql)", to see if you got what you expected.  Then simply 'exec immediate v_sql..

Comment: @EdStevens the general answer is because i'm a programming noob, as you can tell by my bad question, and wasn't aware that what i'm using is called dynamic sql. Originally, i wanted the stage2 table to be a table and couldn't execute that without `execute immediate`. But then I realized that what I actually wanted was a view. When I take out `execute immediate`, it gives me an error `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare...`.  Am i doing something wrong? What do you mean by "assign the constructed SQL to a variable"?

Comment: @EdStevens i would like to understand your debugging advice, but nothing you said starting with "you should assign the constructed SQL to a variable" means anything to me. I don't even know how I can ask a more specific question about it because my general reaction to that is "what is that and what do you mean and how do i write that?". If you wouldn't mind explaining it in more basic terms, I would very much like to understand. Or you could just give me a phrase to google if what you're describing has a name.

Comment: I was going to show you how to do the debugging in an answer, so it could be formatted. But due to the downvotes it has been closed and not accepting answers. "assign the constructed sql to a variable means to NOT execut the sql, but simple to assign the sql statement itself to a variable:  'v_sql := 'select sysdate from dual';.  Then display it: 'dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);'.  Then execute it: 'execute immediate v_sql;'. The dbms_ouput is for debugging purposes and should be removed from final, production code.

Comment: Also you should NOT be creating tables and views inside a procedure.  Those are static objects that should be created one time. If you need a 'temporary' working table, look up 'oracle global temporary tables'.

Comment: @EdStevens thanks. So stage1 is an external table and stage2 is a view, which i use to insert into a real table. I can't make stage1 a GTT because that's not supported. Should I attempt to make stage2 a GTT? I thought views were recreated every time you query them, so i thought that makes them not static. I'm not exactly sure what I would gain if I made stage2 a GTT rather than a view. Am i missing something obvious?

Comment: If STAGE1 is an external table, then no you don't want it to be a GTT. Two totally separate concepts for two totally separate purposes.  Views are nothing but pre-defined queries.  They are NOT recreated every time they are queried.  The _results they return_ may very well be different, but the view itself is - again - just a predefined query.  Define it once, outside of your procedure.  The result of a query is derived when it, itself, is queried - not when it is defined with CREATE VIEW..

Comment: @EdStevens Yeah that makes sense. I moved creating the view out of my procedure. thank you for all your input and patience! I'd like to ask one last question, which may possibly be my dumbest question. I can't use `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line` unless i first run `set serveroutput on;` every time I start a cession. That seems really inefficient. And it seems that I can't just put `set serveroutput on;` into my procedure. Which seems like an even more ridiculous solution. Is there a way to permanently enable the use of the `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line` command?

Comment: It only seems odd and inefficient because you don't understand the working of dbms_output. It simply writes to a buffer, to be processed (or not) by the calling client.  SET SERVEROUT ON is a directive _to sqlplus_, telling it to display the contents of that buffer _when control is returned to sqlplus from a pl/sql procedure_,

Comment: @EdStevens I'm sorry, I don't understand, is that a reason for why I can't permanently turn serveroutput on? It's fine if I can't do that. Also, I decided to check compile and execution time for the procedures with and without the `execute immediate + create view` part. The compile time wasn't too different, but the execution was about 10 times slower when i defined the tables outside. Is that weird? It's not a super huge deal because the execution was only like 2 seconds for the scenario where I define the tables outside of the procedure. I just figured that it would take less time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111940/discussion-between-edstevens-and-ellie-lumen).

Comment: let's plan a chat to discuss further. SO doesn't like extended comment/discussions.  I'm available tomorrow between 7:00 am and 2:00  PM, US Central Daylight time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is missing here:

```
SELECT  
    ind_var_number,
    study_id,
    char_id                     --> here
    valid,
    dose_number,
    ext.concentration,
```

and here :

```
INTO mouse_efficacy 
        (
        ind_var_number,
        study_id,
        char_id --> here
        valid,
```